# Is there a way to access the next line with getline() with c++?

Tags: c++, getline

I am trying to access the next line to check if I would like to change a variable or not. Specifically, I want to check if the difference between the current value and the next one is less than a number, if it is not than I would like to assign a different value to a variable, but if it its than I want to retain the value I have now. My question is, is there a way to "look ahead" with getline(), kind of like an equivalent of i+1 in a for loop.

Comment: Once `getline` gets a line, that line is got. It's no longer in the stream. No one is stopping you from reading that line, caching it somewhere, and checking for a cached line before reading a fresh one.

Comment: please include a [mcve] of your code in the question. I am certain that there is a simple solution to your problem, but talking about code without looking at the code is very difficult

Comment: Outside of `getline`, the concept of _acquiring the same data twice_ hints at a design that is not ideal.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to defer acting on the first line until the second is parsed.

Then you can decide whether to use a content from the first line or modify it.